# My program is locking up and doesn't seem to do what it's supposed to. What have I done wrong?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm a newbie to C programming and I'm up to learning about strings and arrays. My latest challenge is to read in a string, calculate the frequency of each letter and output these including non-letters.

I've written the program but it either locks up or just stops. I can't get it to start the count. Where have I gone wrong?

*NB: My lecturer has some particular views on syntax that other people don't necessarily share. I'm going to stick with the syntax that's going to keep my lecturer happy so please don't pick on the "return (0);" at the end of the main function.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

const int COUNT = 27;
const int STRSIZE = 100;

                counter[c]++;
                c++;
            }
            else 
                if((letterfreq[i] < 'a') || (letterfreq[i] > 'z'))
                {   
                    counter[26]++;
                }
        }
    }

    return;
}

void printFreq(int counter[], int COUNT)
{
    int c;

    in the string.\n", counter[26]);

    return;
}

char promptReset(char reset)
{
    printf("Would you like to calculate the letter frequency of another string? (Y/N)\n");
    scanf("%c%*c", &reset);

    tolower(reset);

    return(reset);
}

int main()
{
```

Comment: but we can suggest `int main(void)` over `int main()`, right?

Comment: `while(letterfreq[i] != '\0')` Cause an infinite loop Because this loop `i` is not updated

Comment: This code has major syntax errors. I guess you have made a copy-paste error somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

In your code,

```
 tolower(letterfreq[STRSIZE]);
```

is overruning allocated memory, which in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Remember, C array index is `0` based.

That said,

1. I don't see the point of the whole statement here. Maybe you'd want to have a look at the man page of `tolower(http://linux.die.net/man/3/tolower)` one again.
2. There is no need to pass `COUNT`, `STRSIZE` as arguments to functions.

Comment: I'm trying to convert the whole lot to lower case so I only have to worry about counting a through z instead of a to z and A to Z.

There is no need to pass COUNT, STRSIZE as arguments to functions. (lecturer syntax)

Comment: @PaigeAngels that. my friend, you have to do using a loop. Also, keep an eye of the _valid_ index, ok?